# Pass Multiple value inside variable of WITH and END WITH in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am currently developing module in which it initialize value on the basis of `if/else` condition inside `WITH/ENDWITH` tag of `DJANGO1.9`.

Example

```
{%with main_value=xxx(my fetched value) current_value='button button-red' %}

............

 ............

{%endwith%}
```

So I am passing `if/else` condition inside this `WITH/ENDWITH`
But it is not accepting `current_value` as there is space between two words.Now my question is How to ignore this space and consider value of `current_value` as single word?

Comment: What's the exact syntax of your first part? I have a local object `page`. If I do:

    `{% with foo=page.title bar="two words" %}
    <p>
    {{ foo }}<br>
    {{ bar }}
    </p>
    {% endwith %}`

then it displays as expected:

"<Title of my page> two words"

Check the syntax of what you've represented as `main_value=xxx(my fetched value)`

Comment: Before {%with %} i had fetched one object from database and then  i had passed object.one_column_value in place of xxx that's why i had put in bracket "(my fetched value)". And Yes your example is perfect but I am passing my value as 2 classes which comes from css.So i have to put as i explained it means whole current_value  with space in it.

Comment: So the syntax you represent as `current_value='button button-red'` is _not_ how it looks in your template file? Can you represent in your question exactly what is written in your template file. Even still `{% with baz="two words" %} {% with foo=page.title bar=baz %}` seems similar to what you describe, and still produces the same output.

Comment: "it is not accepting current_value as there is space between two words", What does happen? errors? nothing displayed?

Comment: nimasmi: @Sayse:Example :it looks like : <a href={% some url%} class ={{current_value}}>.It works perfectly when current_value="button".But during current_value="button button-red" as i had found out it came in browser as: <a href="mylink" class="btn" btn-red=""> So its not taking both values. I actually want it as <a href="mylink" class="button button-red">

Comment: To reiterate what was said before, `'button button-red'` would be treated as a single string, you should try to show code that would demonstrate the issue you're having

Comment: Code : {% with value=obj.current_status value1="btn btn-green" value2='btn-yellow'  %}
 {% if value == 'True' %}
  <a href="{% url 'page2'  %}" class={{value1}} > 
  {{value}}
  </a>
 {% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'page2'  %}" class={{value2}}>
  {{value}}
  </a>
 {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

Comment: `class={{value1}}` should be `class="{{value1}}"`. (Whether this fixes the problem or not.)

Comment: @Risadinha: Thanks.Its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussion on the question above, it looks like it's not in the way you're using the Django `{% with %}` tag, but the way that you're then using the reassigned variable in your HTML tag. Change it from

```
<a href={% some_url %} class={{ current_value }}>
```

to

```
<a href={% some_url %} class="{{ current_value }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
{% include '../components/template.html' with new_object=object %}
```